# Basic Equation Simplification

Tags: probability

I was reading the solution manual of a probability book, and i failed to understand the below simplification

The equation:

\begin{align*}
  F_y(y) &= 1 - F_x(x) \\ &= 1 - (1 - e^{-2x}) U(x) \\ &= e^{-2x} U(x)
\end{align*}

where,
$$U(x) = 1_{[0,\infty)} (x)$$

I do not get how we moved from the second line to the third one. I think it is pretty easy but I'm unable to get it.

Comment: There are two cases. It is clearly true if f $x\ge 0$ but looks wrong if $x<0$

Comment: Yupp, As U is an indicator function. Got it thank you!